# Displaying image in an Interactive Report

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I am using APEX 21.1. I am building a clinic management system. I have an interactive report based on a join between two tables `SELECT e.id examination_id,E.DIAGNOSIS,dbms_lob.getlength(a.img) img,  a.id,attachment_id FROM examination e JOIN examination_attachment a ON A.EXAMINATION_ID = e.id`. The examination could have many attachments. This is the result of the query.
[image]
I changed `IMG` column's type to `Display Image`. When it asks for `BLOB ATTRIBUTES`, I set table name to `examination_attachment`. That's the table that have the images. And I enter the `primary key` as the table's PK(`id`). The page displays error `No data found`. The SQL query returns that `id` duplicated when there is more than one row in the examination_attachment table. I think that's the reason behind the error but not sure. I created a view with the same select statement without the `dbms_lob....` part. Just selected the IMG column. And in BLOB attributes, I set the table to the view name, and the primary key as the `attachment_id` because it's the column that's not duplicated. And it worked. But I need to get it to work without views and I need to know if the cause of the error is right?

Comment: Can you try this? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35127/GUID-6A358F64-7957-4C1E-B552-385B46E9C093.htm#AEAPI129